# React doesnt work with Path and Prefix in Traefik

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, react-router, traefik

I have a React App, that I build with the following Dockerfile

```
# base image
FROM node:latest as builder

# set working directory
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY app/package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install react-scripts@1.1.1 -g

COPY ./app/usr/src/app
# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]

# production environment
FROM nginx:alpine
RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY conf /etc/nginx
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build /etc/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Then I run this with the following Docker Compose

```
build: .
labels:
 - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:www.example.com;PathPrefix:/path"
 - "traefik.protocol=http"
 - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=https"
 - "traefik.port=80"
 - "traefik.enable=true"
restart: always
```

When calling `example.com/path` I get a lot of 404 Errors, as the React App is not looking for path, but in the root of `example.com`.
The App is woking when run without PathPrefix and calling `example.com` directly.

Comment: What is (or isn't) in `/etc/nginx/html` in the final image?  What is (or isn't) in `/usr/src/app/build` in the builder image, and why (or why not)?

Comment: in those folders is the same data of course and it's the react build, what comes in there. so there will be index.html and so on

Comment: I get a feeling the problem is with how the react app builds URLs (not prefixing them with /path) and not with the traefik config. Can you access the expected /path/ URLs correctly manually with curl etc?

Answer (score 2):

Your app doesn't know that traefik is adding a prefix.

You need to specify `homepage` property in `package.json` file to modify every relative URLs that will be used in your app. After building your app using `npm run-script build` it should be fine.

```
{
  "homepage": "/path"
}
```

[react documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#building-for-relative-paths)

Answer (score 0):

I have arrived to a solution to your problem. Let me explain:

1. The "default" path in production environments for our project
   is normally `/sforms`
2. I wanted to serve the built package -without rebuild- from any path
   in production environments, so `"homepage": "."` was mandatory.

   Example: `/sforms_1.0`, `/sforms_legacy`... etc.

So I have reconfigured the script "start" in package.json in the following way:

`"start": "cross-env PUBLIC_URL=/sforms react-scripts start"`

In this way I'm able to start my dev environment under `/sforms`,
avoiding the "magic" of traefik, but keeping the "homepage": ".".

So in Traefik I only have to redirect all the calls starting
with the prefix `/sforms` to my development server, and all the cases
are covered.

Let me paste here my Traefik configuration for that component. Maybe it could be useful:

```
http:
  routers:
    debugging-oe-sl-form:
      service: debugging-oe-sl-form-proxy
      rule: "PathPrefix(`/sforms`)"
      entryPoints:
        - web

  services:
    debugging-oe-sl-form-proxy:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "http://host.docker.internal:3000"
```